# How to change height of image when viewed on mobile

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I am a newbie to CSS. My problem is as follows:
I have 3 sections with 2 columns in each. When I view it on mobile, it does stack correctly, but the image height is very low.

My image is set as a background in the column and set to cover.

What CSS can I use and where do I add the class once created?

Damn...I must sound so dumb.

Hope you lovely people know what I mean!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: you must use media queries to do so. What do you mean by "the image height is very low ?" Do you have some codepen, or anything so we can see what you mean and give you a precise answer ? And don't worry, there's no dumb question, everyone is a newbie one day.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Here is the page I am experimenting: https://konnekt.net.za/home-2-2/. It shows the full width for mobile view, but it's height does not resize automatically and only shows a slither. The images are set as BG images in the column, set to COVER and I selected Equal Height for the rows.

Comment: I found the solution!

Comment: /* Responsive images */
@media (max-width: 671px) {
 .min-height {
  min-height:450px;
 }
}